# Jquery position snippet issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand someone else's codes...he has the following:

```
    var positionAt = horizontalPosition + ' ' + verticalPosition;
    var positionOffset = String(horizontalOffset + ' ' + verticalOffset);

   //i don't understand the codes below. I don't think Jquery position method support at and of attribues....

   $tooltipElement.position({at: positionAt, of: $element, my: 'left top', offset: positionOffset});

                $element.hover(function(){
                            $instance = $(this).css({'cursor': 'pointer'});
                            $('#tooltip-' + $instance.attr('id') ).fadeIn('fast');
                }, function(){
                            $instance = $(this).css({'cursor': 'auto'});
                            $('#tooltip-' + $instance.attr('id') ).fadeOut('fast');
                });
```

I am not sure what the position method with At, of and my attributes for. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's using the [UI/Position plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position), in which the position function takes `my`, `at` and `of` parameters :

> **my :**
>   Defines which position on the element being positioned to align
>   with the target element: "horizontal vertical" alignment. A single
>   value such as "right" will default to "right center", "top" will
>   default to "center top" (following CSS convention). Acceptable values:
>   "top", "center", "bottom", "left", "right". Example: "left top" or
>   "center center"
>
> **at :** 
>   Defines which position on the target element to align the
>   positioned element against: "horizontal vertical" alignment. A single
>   value such as "right" will default to "right center", "top" will
>   default to "center top" (following CSS convention). Acceptable values:
>   "top", "center", "bottom", "left", "right". Example: "left top" or
>   "center center"
>
> **of :** 
>   Element to position against. If you provide a selector, the first
>   matching element will be used. If you provide a jQuery object, the
>   first element will be used. If you provide an event object, the pageX
>   and pageY properties will be used. Example: "#top-menu"